# ui-grid selection on right click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to be able to select the row when there was a right click on the row.

So far I have the following solution (I have the idea from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/9Gg18uZqGV8)):

I create a right click directive like this:

```
app.directive('rightClick', function($parse) {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       var fn = $parse(attrs.rightClick);
       element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
       scope.$apply(function() {
           event.preventDefault();
               fn(scope, {$event:event});
           });
       });
    };
});
```

And then I can add a function in my controller that will be called:

```
 $scope.rightClick = function (event) {
     var scope = angular.element(event.toElement).scope();
     if (scope.row.entity !== undefined) {
         //... select element by calling gridApi
     }
 };
```

Adding the directive with the attribute `right-click="rightClick($event)"` is of course required.

The problem with this solution is that it relies on `element.scope()` which is a debug feature of angular and will not be available if debug informations are disable in production.

So now I am looking for an alternative solution that works without `element.scope()`. So the question is: "How can I select the element on right-click without relying on angular debug features".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row id is stored on the cell element id which can be used to identify which cell was clicked:

```
$scope.rightClick = function (event) {
  var element = angular.element(event.toElement);

  //get cellId which for the thrid row should something like this
  //1464688691229-2-uiGrid-0006-cell
  var id = element[0].parentElement.id;

  var regex = /(\d+)/g
  var result = id.match(regex);
  var rowIndex = parseInt(result[1]); //extract second numeric match

  $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRowByVisibleIndex(rowIndex);      
};
```

I'd say you probably need to experiment to see if that id is the visible index or the index of the source data. I'm not sure but I've put a working example here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/b2RKW0hdtFk1ZOLn1XsS?p=preview

Comment: Interesting solution. Unfortunately I have no id on the cell divs. Probably it's due to the fact that I use a custom row template.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a custom attribute on the cell DOM elements? Note also that the id is on the parent element not the cell contents.

Comment: I had to change my row template such that it has some properties of the original row template (see 'ui-grid/ui-grid-row' template in ui-grid source code). Thx.

Comment: I found some issue with this implementation when you have pagination in grid. The index will remain same for different rows when you scroll the grid. So rowIndex 5 for one row will be the same rowIndex 5 for another row after scroll. Any idea how to overcome this issue??

Comment: @VinayGayakwad Sorry, I don't have any additional info on that use case. But if you do find the answer please do post it back here.

Comment: @TomMakin I added values of rowindex in cellClass for each item with some prefix. I got the index values using  "grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)". After which I read the classname for the cell clicked and will fetch the rowindex. Pretty work around , yeah but works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with overriding the debug behaviour you could go with:

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()
```

Not pretty, but it would work.

Source: https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes

Comment: I am looking for a solution that works without debug information.

Comment: Fair cop. See second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define row template with **ng-mouseover** reference to some scope method (see below $scope.selectRowOnMouseOver) which will set row (under mouse cursor) to some scope variable. Then you can use this variable to set selection in your rightClick method:

Define row template:

```
     //define row template with ng-mouseover reference to scope method
    $scope.resultsGrid.rowTemplate =
        "<div ng-dblclick=\"grid.appScope.doubleClickOnRow(row, $event)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in" +
        " colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell':" +
        " col.isRowHeader }\" ng-mouseover=\"grid.appScope.selectRowOnMouseOver(row)\" ui-grid-cell></div>";
```

Define method which will set row under cursor in scope variable (or set selection on this row right away):

```
    $scope.selectRowOnMouseOver = function (row) {
        $scope.rowUnderMouse =  row;
        //you can also select row right here or in other methods using above variable
        $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
        row.setSelected(true);
    };
```

Use scope variable in your rightClick method:

```
    $scope.rightClick = function (event) {
        var row = $scope.rowUnderMouse;
        //clear other selections
        $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
        //set row as selected
        row.setSelected(true);
        //...
    }
```